# How to create SCOM management pack monitor with three states

Tags: c#, monitoring, health-monitoring, scom, management-pack

I develop integration with SCOM. But I am a green hand in it.

I have created management pack XML and it works fine.

Please review management pack below:

```
<ManagementPack xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ContentReadable="true">
  <Manifest>
    <Identity>
      <ID>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring</ID>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    </Identity>
    <Name>CloudMonix Resource Monitoring Pack</Name>
    <References>
      <Reference Alias="System">
        <ID>System.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.5.8501.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="SystemCenter">
        <ID>Microsoft.SystemCenter.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.0.8437.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
    </References>
  </Manifest>
  <TypeDefinitions>
    <EntityTypes>
      <ClassTypes>
        <ClassType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" Accessibility="Public" Abstract="false" Base="System!System.Entity" Hosted="false" Singleton="false">
          <Property ID="ResourceId" Type="string" Key="true" CaseSensitive="false" Length="256" MinLength="1" />
          <Property ID="ResourceType" Type="string" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" Length="256" MinLength="1" />
          <Property ID="ResourceStatus" Type="string" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" Length="256" MinLength="1" />
          <Property ID="ResourceGroups" Type="string" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" Length="1024" MinLength="1" />
        </ClassType>
      </ClassTypes>
    </EntityTypes>
  </TypeDefinitions>
  <Presentation>
    <Views>
      <View ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="true" Target="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" TypeID="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.StateViewType" Visible="true">
        <Category>Operations</Category>
        <Criteria>
          <InMaintenanceMode>false</InMaintenanceMode>
        </Criteria>
        <Presentation>

          <ColumnInfo Index="0" SortIndex="0" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="true" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Descending">
            <Name>State</Name>
            <Id>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>

          <ColumnInfo Index="1" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Type</Name>
            <Id>ResourceType</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="2" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Name</Name>
            <Id>DisplayName</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="3" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Status</Name>
            <Id>ResourceStatus</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="4" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Groups</Name>
            <Id>ResourceGroups</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
        </Presentation>
        <Target />
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Folders>
      <Folder ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder" Accessibility="Public" ParentFolder="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.Monitoring.ViewFolder.Root" />
    </Folders>
    <FolderItems>
      <FolderItem ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" Folder="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder" />
    </FolderItems>
  </Presentation>
  <LanguagePacks>
    <LanguagePack ID="ENU" IsDefault="false">
      <DisplayStrings>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource Monitoring</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder">
          <Name>CloudMonix Folder</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource View</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceId">
          <Name>Resource Id</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceType">
          <Name>Resource Type</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceStatus">
          <Name>Resource Status</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceGroups">
          <Name>Resource Groups</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
      </DisplayStrings>
    </LanguagePack>
  </LanguagePacks>
</ManagementPack>
```

I have installed this management pack using SCOM [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb437500.aspx) and [ImportManagementPack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh329087.aspx) method.

Also I have developed Inbound Connector as described in [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh329020.aspx).

I can send discovery data, performance metrics and events using my connector. And it works fine.

The result of successful import is on the screenshot:
[image]

The monitoring objects were created correctly.

But these objects have `Not monitored` Health State.

**My main question is how to change Health State?**

My logic for Health State is very simple:

1. If `Resource Status` (please look this property in the screenshot and in management pack XML) property is equal to `Ready` then Health State is `Success`.
2. If `Resource Status` property is equal to `Down` then Health State is `Error`.
3. Otherwise Health State is `Not monitored`.

I have reviewed many documents ([here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/momteam/2008/03/14/operations-manager-2007-sdk-documentation-updates/) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh457603%28v=sc.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) and found that I need to create monitor, monitor types, expression rules for changing Health State.

Also I have checked XML examples [here](https://systemcenter.wiki/?GetCategory=System%20Center%20Operations%20Manager%20%28version%201801%29).

But I don't understand how to define my expressions and how to add necessary information to management pack XML file.

The best answer for me is complete XML example with implementation of expression rules of my logic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all let me warn you, that this is not an appropriate way to monitor something via discoverable class properties. SCOM database is designed in assumption, that all configuration properties are static. Say, disk size or number of CPUs doesn't change often. By doing that, you causes configuration churn. Please refer to Kevin Holman's article for details: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinholman/2009/10/04/what-is-config-churn/

However, you still can do that. Please refer to the MP XML below. The main idea is to make a fake script which packages class property in a Property Bag, so then a Condition Detection can analyse it.

Please be aware, that you cannot set a monitor into "Not Initialized" state explicitly. A monitor is not initialized only if:

1. It's been just created.
2. Exits from maintenance mode.

A monitoring workflow can send a signal to set monitor to either healthy, warning or critical state, but if no signal comes, then health state preserves its last state.

Also note, that I used 2007 scheme and aligned references, as well as changed aliases. I haven't tested it, but it is compiled with no errors. ENU is a default language now.

```xml
<ManagementPack ContentReadable="true" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Manifest>
    <Identity>
      <ID>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring</ID>
      <Version>1.0.0.6</Version>
    </Identity>
    <Name>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring</Name>
    <References>
      <Reference Alias="SC">
        <ID>Microsoft.SystemCenter.Library</ID>
        <Version>6.1.7221.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="Windows">
        <ID>Microsoft.Windows.Library</ID>
        <Version>6.1.7221.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="Health">
        <ID>System.Health.Library</ID>
        <Version>6.1.7221.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="System">
        <ID>System.Library</ID>
        <Version>6.1.7221.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
    </References>
  </Manifest>
  <TypeDefinitions>
    <EntityTypes>
      <ClassTypes>
        <ClassType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" Accessibility="Public" Abstract="false" Base="System!System.Entity" Hosted="false" Singleton="false">
          <Property ID="ResourceId" Type="string" Key="true" CaseSensitive="false" MinLength="1" Length="256" />
          <Property ID="ResourceType" Type="string" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" MinLength="1" Length="256" />
          <Property ID="ResourceStatus" Type="string" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" MinLength="1" Length="256" />
          <Property ID="ResourceGroups" Type="string" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" MinLength="1" Length="1024" />
        </ClassType>
      </ClassTypes>
    </EntityTypes>
    <ModuleTypes>
      <DataSourceModuleType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.DataSource" Accessibility="Internal" Batching="false">
        <Configuration>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="IntervalSeconds" type="xsd:integer" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SyncTime" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="ResourceStatus" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <OverrideableParameters>
          <OverrideableParameter ID="IntervalSeconds" Selector="$Config/IntervalSeconds$" ParameterType="int" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="SyncTime" Selector="$Config/SyncTime$" ParameterType="string" />
        </OverrideableParameters>
        <ModuleImplementation>
          <Composite>
            <MemberModules>
              <DataSource ID="DS_Scheduler" TypeID="System!System.Scheduler">
                <Scheduler>
                  <SimpleReccuringSchedule>
                    <Interval Unit="Seconds">$Config/IntervalSeconds$</Interval>
                    <SyncTime>$Config/SyncTime$</SyncTime>
                  </SimpleReccuringSchedule>
                  <ExcludeDates />
                </Scheduler>
              </DataSource>
              <ProbeAction ID="PA_PackageData" TypeID="Windows!Microsoft.Windows.PowerShellPropertyBagProbe">
                <ScriptName>Set-PropertyBagWithValue.ps1</ScriptName>
                <ScriptBody>

param($data)
$api = New-Object -comObject 'MOM.ScriptAPI'
$bag = $api.CreatePropertyBag()
$bag.AddValue("ResourceStatus", $data)
$bag

                </ScriptBody>
                <Parameters>
                  <Parameter>
                    <Name>data</Name>
                    <Value>$Config/ResourceStatus$</Value>
                  </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
                <TimeoutSeconds>300</TimeoutSeconds>
              </ProbeAction>
            </MemberModules>
            <Composition>
              <Node ID="PA_PackageData">
                <Node ID="DS_Scheduler" />
              </Node>
            </Composition>
          </Composite>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <OutputType>System!System.PropertyBagData</OutputType>
      </DataSourceModuleType>
    </ModuleTypes>
    <MonitorTypes>
      <UnitMonitorType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.MonitorType" Accessibility="Internal">
        <MonitorTypeStates>
          <MonitorTypeState ID="Ready" NoDetection="false" />
          <MonitorTypeState ID="Down" NoDetection="false" />
        </MonitorTypeStates>
        <Configuration>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="IntervalSeconds" type="xsd:integer" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SyncTime" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="ResourceStatus" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <OverrideableParameters>
          <OverrideableParameter ID="IntervalSeconds" Selector="$Config/IntervalSeconds$" ParameterType="int" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="SyncTime" Selector="$Config/SyncTime$" ParameterType="string" />
        </OverrideableParameters>
        <MonitorImplementation>
          <MemberModules>
            <DataSource ID="DS_ResourceStatus" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.DataSource">
              <IntervalSeconds>$Config/IntervalSeconds$</IntervalSeconds>
              <SyncTime>$Config/SyncTime$</SyncTime>
              <ResourceStatus>$Config/ResourceStatus$</ResourceStatus>
            </DataSource>
            <ConditionDetection ID="CD_Ready" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter">
              <Expression>
                <SimpleExpression>
                  <ValueExpression>
                    <XPathQuery Type="String">Property[@Name='ResourceStatus']</XPathQuery>
                  </ValueExpression>
                  <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                  <ValueExpression>
                    <Value Type="String">Ready</Value>
                  </ValueExpression>
                </SimpleExpression>
              </Expression>
            </ConditionDetection>
            <ConditionDetection ID="CD_Down" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter">
              <Expression>
                <SimpleExpression>
                  <ValueExpression>
                    <XPathQuery Type="String">Property[@Name='ResourceStatus']</XPathQuery>
                  </ValueExpression>
                  <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                  <ValueExpression>
                    <Value Type="String">Down</Value>
                  </ValueExpression>
                </SimpleExpression>
              </Expression>
            </ConditionDetection>
          </MemberModules>
          <RegularDetections>
            <RegularDetection MonitorTypeStateID="Ready">
              <Node ID="CD_Ready">
                <Node ID="DS_ResourceStatus" />
              </Node>
            </RegularDetection>
            <RegularDetection MonitorTypeStateID="Down">
              <Node ID="CD_Down">
                <Node ID="DS_ResourceStatus" />
              </Node>
            </RegularDetection>
          </RegularDetections>
        </MonitorImplementation>
      </UnitMonitorType>
    </MonitorTypes>
  </TypeDefinitions>
  <Monitoring>
    <Monitors>
      <UnitMonitor ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="true" Target="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" ParentMonitorID="Health!System.Health.AvailabilityState" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.MonitorType" ConfirmDelivery="false">
        <Category>AvailabilityHealth</Category>
        <AlertSettings AlertMessage="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor.AlertMessage">
          <AlertOnState>Error</AlertOnState>
          <AutoResolve>true</AutoResolve>
          <AlertPriority>Normal</AlertPriority>
          <AlertSeverity>MatchMonitorHealth</AlertSeverity>
        </AlertSettings>
        <OperationalStates>
          <OperationalState ID="Ready" MonitorTypeStateID="Ready" HealthState="Success" />
          <OperationalState ID="Down" MonitorTypeStateID="Down" HealthState="Error" />
        </OperationalStates>
        <Configuration>
          <IntervalSeconds>300</IntervalSeconds>
          <SyncTime />
          <ResourceStatus>$Target/Property[Type="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource"]/ResourceStatus$</ResourceStatus>
        </Configuration>
      </UnitMonitor>
    </Monitors>
  </Monitoring>
  <Presentation>
    <Views>
      <View ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="true" Target="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" TypeID="SC!Microsoft.SystemCenter.StateViewType" Visible="true">
        <Category>Operations</Category>
        <Criteria>
          <InMaintenanceMode>false</InMaintenanceMode>
        </Criteria>
        <Presentation>
          <ColumnInfo Index="0" SortIndex="0" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="true" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Descending">
            <Name>State</Name>
            <Id>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="1" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Type</Name>
            <Id>ResourceType</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="2" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Name</Name>
            <Id>DisplayName</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="3" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Status</Name>
            <Id>ResourceStatus</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="4" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Groups</Name>
            <Id>ResourceGroups</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
        </Presentation>
        <Target />
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Folders>
      <Folder ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder" Accessibility="Public" ParentFolder="SC!Microsoft.SystemCenter.Monitoring.ViewFolder.Root" />
    </Folders>
    <FolderItems>
      <FolderItem ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" Folder="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder" />
    </FolderItems>
    <StringResources>
      <StringResource ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor.AlertMessage" />
    </StringResources>
  </Presentation>
  <LanguagePacks>
    <LanguagePack ID="ENU" IsDefault="true">
      <DisplayStrings>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource Monitoring</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder">
          <Name>CloudMonix Folder</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource View</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceId">
          <Name>Resource Id</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceType">
          <Name>Resource Type</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceStatus">
          <Name>Resource Status</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceGroups">
          <Name>Resource Groups</Name>
          <Description></Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor">
          <Name>Resource Status Unit Monitor</Name>
          <Description>Resource Status Unit Monitor</Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor.AlertMessage">
          <Name>Alert</Name>
          <Description>Alert</Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor" SubElementID="Ready">
          <Name>Ready</Name>
          <Description>Ready</Description>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.ResourceStatus.UnitMonitor" SubElementID="Down">
          <Name>Down</Name>
          <Description>Down</Description>
        </DisplayString>
      </DisplayStrings>
      <KnowledgeArticles></KnowledgeArticles>
    </LanguagePack>
  </LanguagePacks>
</ManagementPack>
```

Comment: it is very helpfull! I have reviewed Kevin Holman's article and I think we need to change our integration logic. Also I have found Jakub Oleksy [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jakuboleksy/2007/08/22/setting-the-state-of-an-instance-programmatically/). We can change Health State using events and this solution will be more efficient. Am I right?

Comment: thanks for your feedback and thank you for Jakub's article. I didn't know about this method. Will be really interesting to learn details about it. However, making a reasonable assumption, that the event method works, this method will be way more efficient. Just out of curiosity, why not run actual query to monitored objects right on SCOM? Why connector is used?

Comment: we have cloud monitoring [system](http://www.cloudmonix.com/) and we try to implement integration from our system to SCOM. Our user can create many types of integrations inside our system, but he has no access to data outside.

Comment: I see, since you have your targets monitored in other system, it wont make much sense to monitor it twice, so your approach is reasonable. In order to set health state of an "artificial" instance like yours, you can try your finding, as well as: 1. Create an event (log file or windows log) driven monitor. Use standard workflows to catch a pattern or Windows event. Just ensure that these events are posted to all management servers, or use a network share for the log file. 2. Have a look at Microsoft's implementation of the "Health Service Heartbeat Failure" monitor.

Comment: Could you help with new SCOM [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721626/insert-performance-data-to-dw-database) please?